# asmack file sending: transfer status = null

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am using asmack 18-0.8.9.
below is my sending file method

```
public void send()
{

    configureProviderManager(connection);

    FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);
    FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("xxxxx@jabber.ccc.de/Smack");

    File file = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1385869353956.jpg");
    try {
        Log.d("file sending",file.getAbsolutePath()+" "+file.getName());
        configureProviderManager(connection);
       transfer.sendFile(file, "test_file");
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(!transfer.isDone()) {
           if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
              System.out.println("ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());
           } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.cancelled)
                            || transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.refused)) {
              System.out.println("Cancelled!!! " + transfer.getError());
           }
           try {
              Thread.sleep(1000L);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }

        if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.refused))
                 System.out.println("refused  " + transfer.getError());
        else if( transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error))
             System.out.println(" error " + transfer.getError());
        else if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.cancelled))
           System.out.println(" cancelled  " + transfer.getError());
        else
           System.out.println("Success");


    }
```

Below is my receiver part

```
FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
        manager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
           public void fileTransferRequest(final FileTransferRequest request) {
              new Thread(){
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                    IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
                    Log.d("receive","file name: "+transfer.getFileName());


                    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
                    dir.mkdirs();
                    File file = new File(dir+transfer.getFileName());
                        try {
                            transfer.recieveFile(file);
                        } catch (XMPPException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                        }
                        while(!transfer.isDone()) {
                           try{
                              Thread.sleep(1000L);
                           }catch (Exception e) {
                              Log.d("receive","thread sleep"+ e.getMessage());

                           }
                           if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {

                              Log.d("error","error status"+ transfer.getError() + "");
                           }
                           if(transfer.getException() != null) {

                              transfer.getException().printStackTrace();
                           }
                        }

                 };
               }.start();
            }
         });
```

I can successfully receive file from other desktop clients like psi, pidgin. When I try to send file from my android app to other desktop client or my own app installed on other phone they do not receive any XMPP message. While when I send file from other desktop client to my android app I can see XMPP message and successfully receive message.

Below is my configureProviderManager method

```
public void configureProviderManager() {


    ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
    ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
    ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());

    }
```

Comment: did you solved this issue? i am getting same exception.